# Ember calculation with model attributes

Tags: ember.js

I want to calculate the total result for a fare. You can see here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yudofozoqu/1/

It is composed by value quantity:

```
{{input value=quantity}}
```

multiplied by the specific fare which can be selected in the select option:

```
{{view Em.Select prompt="test" contentBinding="controllers.fare.content" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.id" selectionBinding="controllers.fare.selectedFare" }}
```

The total result has to correspond to the total value I have set up in my model:

```
{{input value=total}}

App.Invoice = DS.Model.extend({
  name        : DS.attr('string'),
  quantity    : DS.attr('string'),
  total       : DS.attr('string')
});

App.Invoice.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   quantity: null,
   total: null
 }
];
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function to watch for changes in the `quantity` and `fare.selectedFare` properties so it can calculate the total. For example:

```
// this should be added to the IndexController
updateTotal: function() {

  // get the reference to the values of fare and quantity
  var quantity = this.get('quantity'),
      fare = this.get('controllers.fare.selectedFare.id');

  // massage them to make sure your stuff is not gonna break
  if (isNaN(fare)) { fare = 0; }
  if (isNaN(quantity)) { quantity = 0; }

  // calculate
  var total = fare * quantity;

  // set the total
  this.set('total', total);

}.observes('quantity', 'controllers.fare.selectedFare')
```

Ok. This works, but consider doing the total calculation in the backend as you save the record (in your server controller) and turn the `total` attribute into a computed property with the same general idea of the code above. Depending on what you are doing, if it involves float/decimal/exotic calculations, (I tend to think that) you can expect more accuracy with static types  (generally on the server) instead of JavaScript

Comment: This works, you touched really good point, beacuse my Ember application (an Invoice Generator) is integrated in Rails, and my idea was to use Ember Controllers for the value calculation, then send them to the  Rails Server which then create the database columns.

This is the article inspired me: http://www.sitepoint.com/ember-todomvc-rails/