# Operations with Select value and Input value in Ember

Tags: ember.js

It's still not really clear to me how can ii can make operations with the Select option values in Ember

This is very simple moltiplication i want to achieve between a value of an Input and Select option value

My code is the following:

My input quantity: `{{input valueBinding=quantity}}`

My Select with the option value: `{{view Ember.Select prompt="Tariffa" value=selectContentTariffa.value content=controller.selectContentTariffa optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.label"}}`

My Input total where i want to show the moltiplication result between quantity and the selected fare:

```
  {{view "total"}}

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="total">
    {{view.total valueBinding=total}}
  </script>
```

This is the view where i set up the moltiplication

```
App.TotalView = Ember.View.extend({
 templateName: 'total',
 tagName: 'input',
 attributeBindings: ['total:value', 'placeholder', 'type'],
 placeholder: null,
 type: 'number',
 total: (function() {
    var res= parseInt(this.get('selectContentTariffa.value')) * parseInt(this.get('quantity'));
   return isNaN(res)?"":res;
    }).property('selectContentTariffa.value', 'quantity')
});
```

Am i doing something wrong in setting up the values `this.get('selectContentTariffa.value')) or this.get('quantity'))` ?

or i am doing an other mistake?

Here i have reproduced my [case](http://jsbin.com/vunime/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Adding a bunch of tags to your questions does not give them more visibility or higher chances of being answered. http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging Usually adding one or two tags will be enough for the experts to see your question.

Comment: Also, it is easier for people to answer your questions if you provide a **minimal** test case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember calculation with model attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913664/ember-calculation-with-model-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you’re confused about how and where to define and access properties. [Here](http://jsbin.com/wepusezawe/2/edit) is a working update to your case. The key mistake is your select’s value binding. You have this:

```
value=selectContentTariffa.value
```

I changed it to this:

```
value=controller.tariffa
```

The value binding tells Ember where to store the selected value. This sets `tariffa` on the controller. In the `total` computed property, you can access the value like this:

```
this.get('controller.tariffa')
```

The same applies to `quantity`.

Comment: Ok, i have finally understood the way it works! But why i can not achieve the binding of the total value? http://jsbin.com/sagaha/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Your code is pretty convoluted and therefore it’s difficult to understand what you’re trying for, but I think if you moved `total` to be a property on the controller instead of a seemingly-unnecessary view, you would have what you want.

Comment: i have made an other question on how achieve the same creating the data record of the values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639316/calculation-computed-properties-in-models-ember

Comment: If the end result is the same, but through a different method, please consider adding your own answer to this question; instead of opening a new question.